# Java - MyBatis - process one record at a time

Tags: java, mybatis, resultset

Using MyBatis `ResultHandler` it's possible to process one result object at a time.
Unfortunately if the `ResultMap` is complex the object won't be complete.
Is there a workaround for that?

I need to extract about 500000 rows, and I'd like to process and discard by single object.

Comment: Can the "discarding condition" be applied in SQL? Why doesn't it complete? Too many rows/memory exhausted, or it's just too slow and times out? Does it throw any error? Half a million row is not a colossal number these days (2018).

Comment: @TheImpaler As of now all the rows are extracted and loaded in memory, then they're processed one by one. I mean, after some benchmark, after having set a decent fetch size, the performance is not bad. But I don't like having to waste memory for nothing (500000 rows may not seem a lot, but how many columns and how much data does they contain? A lot).
Having the ability to fetch and work on a single object at a time, and then let the GC take care of it and the related resources is the better way, imho. What do you think? "Discard" was not the appropriate word, maybe, my bad!

Comment: what do you mean by 'object wont' be complete'? The object will contain data that is defined by mapping and the fields present in the resultset. If you including all the fields you need and map them - the object will be complete.

Comment: @RomanKonoval not if you have collections or associations. MyBatis Java documentation states that it might not be complete at the time is goes through the ResultHandler.

Comment: I see. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ResultHandler` you can try to use [Cursor](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/apidocs/org/apache/ibatis/cursor/Cursor.html) which is `Iterable` and can be used like this (under condition that result is ordered, see above `Cursor` API java doc for details):

MyEntityMapper.java

```
@Select({
      "SELECT *",
      "FROM my_entity",
      "ORDER BY id"
})
Cursor<MyEntity> getEntities();
```

MapperClient.java

```
MyEntityMapper mapper = session.getMapper(MyEntityMapper.class);
try (Cursor<MyEntity> entities = mapper.getEntities()) {
   for (MyEntity entity:entities) {
      // process one entity
   }
}
```

It it more high level abstraction than `ResultHandler` and it does respect all the mappings.

Comment: Yes! Why isn't this documented in the Java API page?!

Comment: No idea. I've just added [PR](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/pull/1310) to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Half a milion rows in memory can be a waste of memory, specially if you have multiple concurrent processes/users running at the same time. You could exhaust the server heap.

You didn't post what database you are using, but since the fetch size worked, I assume it's something like Oracle, DB2, or PostgreSQL.

Now, even if you managed to retrieve the rows in small batches (let's say 1000 at a time), you need to understand that some queries cannot be run gradually, and the database server needs to read all 500000 rows before sending you the first one. This means, even though your web server won't suffer a lot of load, multiple concurrent queries will produce a bottleneck in the database anyway. You would not be fixing the problem, but just transferring it to the database. Not great.

On the other side, have you thought about using some kind of pagination when returning the rows? Some queries allow you do do that very efficiently. For example, the query could return 10,000 rows at a time. But please don't use `OFFSET`; this is highly inefficient for your case. You would need to use [Key Set Pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset), assuming the rows are ordered by a **unique** set of columns.

Finally, why do you need to read so many rows? I would do something like this for a batch/nightly process, but not for online responses. What is your use case?

Comment: Spot on. Oracle DB and it's for a batch-nightly job. I know someone could say "it's night, nobody cares", but I care. Well I refused to use the MyBatis RowBounds, so Offset is implicitly off the game. I considered pagination with ROWNUM, but I thought why not trying the "all + one-at-a-time" road. Isn't pagination risky if rows are being inserted during extraction? Btw, I don't care about putting load on the DB, it's the thing the has most resources.

Comment: Yes, it will be risky if there are other processes inserting rows during the extraction. Maybe you can control that by simply organizing how he batch jobs are run; maybe you could produce a table lock when running (just to be on the safe side). Otherwise, the solution you have right now seems to be the safest one.

Comment: So basically you're confirming there is no way to have the complete single object with MyBatis

Comment: Ah, what about fetching the rows UID only and then paginating on them? The UID is pretty insignificat in size terms. I think that would be a good solution! By paginating I mean using the IN clause (obviously there is a limitation on the number of items in this clause, but it would still be ok to me). Or I could use a JOIN with a temp. table. No cancel that, I can't do it.

Comment: Yes, that could work, assuming there are no major changes to the data, like updated values, or deleted rows.